# Javascript And Xpath

Tags: javascript, xpath

I am using plain old school Javascript - So no jQuery responses please!.

I have loaded in an xml document which kind of looks like this

```
<node>
     <child tags='Foo,Bar'>
          ------ GrandChild Nodes Here
     </child>
     <child tags='Nuts,Bolts'>
          ------ GrandChild Nodes Here
     </child>
      <child tags='Bacon,Eggs'>
          ------ GrandChild Nodes Here
     </child>
</node>
```

What I need to know is if I wanted to get all the children of a node that had been tagged in Foo for example how what I do this using xPath.

Cheers

Steve

Comment: Are you running JS in XML, or did you receive some XML from an AJAX call?

Comment: This is an appcelerator build as well - Not sure if that helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this XPath 1.0 expression:

```
/node/child[
   contains(
      concat(',',@tags,','),
      ',Foo,'
   )
]/node()
```

Comment: @Flack: Yes, we need an urgent upgrade to XPath/XSLT 2.0